# about explorer.exe crashing with window 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, crash

I started notice the problem when I tried to move a file to my external HD, and my explorer.exe just kept crashing, but it will restart back up. later on, I realized that its not just moving files to external HD, it crashes every times when I try to move any files to anywhere. I done many searches about it, but somehow I just couldn't solve the problem. I was wondering if anyone can help me.

I installed 'WinThruster', it supposed fix the error with explorer.exe crashing, it didn't. I was also trying to using DLL Suite, but I'm worried its not gonna do anything again and I would spend money on another program that doesn't work.

I'm not sure what else I can provide other than this right now, if there are not enough details, and anyone can help me find more about it, that would be awesome!!!

help me please!!! thank you!!!

Comment: First get rid of the malware that is "WinThrustsr", after you do that, boot into a minimal configuration and confirm the problem does or does not exhibit itself.

Comment: create a crash dump and share it. I posted here how to do this: http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure if I understand what you mean

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'll let you know asap, thank you

Comment: @magicandre1981 this is the link, https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvTTgGqXPw1egnowz-Px5UCYzgqf

Comment: I posted what I see from the dump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Explorer is crashed by a file called `psdprotect.dll` which belongs to a program called `EgisTec MyWinLocker` (`C:\Program Files (x86)\EgisTec MyWinLocker\x64\psdprotect.dll`). The tool is from 2010, so update or uninstall it:

```
PROBLEM_CLASSES: 



NULL_POINTER_READ
    Tid    [0x15c0]
    Frame  [0x00]: psdprotect


LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 00000000100020be to 00000000100012db

STACK_TEXT:  

00 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects
01 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx
02 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsExImplementation
03 kernel32!WerpReportFaultInternal
04 kernel32!WerpReportFault
05 kernel32!BasepReportFault
06 kernel32!UnhandledExceptionFilter
07 ntdll! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
08 ntdll!_C_specific_handler
09 ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
0a ntdll!RtlDispatchException
0b ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch
0c psdprotect
0d psdprotect
0e shell32!CFSDropTargetHelper::_MoveCopyHIDA
0f shell32!CFSDropTargetHelper::_Drop
10 shell32!CFSDropTargetHelper::s_DoDropThreadProc
11 shlwapi!WrapperThreadProc
12 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk
13 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart

SYMBOL_NAME:  psdprotect+12db

IMAGE_NAME:  psdprotect.dll

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  X64_NULL_POINTER_READ_psdprotect+12db

BUCKET_ID_MODVER_STR:  3.1.210.0

BUCKET_ID_PREFIX_STR:  X64_NULL_POINTER_READ_

FAILURE_PROBLEM_CLASS:  NULL_POINTER_READ

FAILURE_EXCEPTION_CODE:  c0000005

FAILURE_IMAGE_NAME:  psdprotect.dll

OSBUILD:  7601

OSSERVICEPACK:  23418

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 7

OSEDITION:  Windows 7 WinNt (Service Pack 1) SingleUserTS Personal

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2016-04-09 09:00:43

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  160408-2045

BUILDLAB_STR:  win7sp1_ldr

BUILDOSVER_STR:  6.1.7601.23418

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:null_pointer_read_c0000005_psdprotect.dll!unknown

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

0:044> lmvm psdprotect
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
00000000`10000000 00000000`10026000   psdprotect   (export symbols)       psdprotect.dll
    Loaded symbol image file: psdprotect.dll
    Image path: C:\Program Files (x86)\EgisTec MyWinLocker\x64\psdprotect.dll
    Image name: psdprotect.dll
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Fri Apr 16 16:42:14 2010 (4BC87746)
    CheckSum:         00029087
    ImageSize:        00026000
    File version:     3.1.210.0
    Product version:  3.1.210.0
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          4 Unknown Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04e4
    CompanyName:      Egis Technology Inc.
    ProductName:      MyWinLocker
    InternalName:     PSDProtect.dll
    OriginalFilename: PSDProtect.dll
    ProductVersion:   3.1.210.0
    FileVersion:      3.1.210.0
    FileDescription:  PSD DragDrop Protection
    LegalCopyright:   Copyright (C)2008 Egis Technology Inc. All rights reserved.
```

Comment: damn!!! you solve my problem like it was nothing! thank you so much!!!

Comment: you're welcome. When you know how to do it, it is easy. Open the dmp in windbg, setup symbols https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311503 and run **!analyze -v**